# Adding label to polar chart in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts, annotations

I am adding some labels or annotations to my plot. I want the labels to be positioned exactly in-between the plot and axis angle. I am using "pad = 20" to create a gap between the plot and the axis tick labels and "label_pos_r" to adjust the position of the labels. Unfortunately "label_pos_r" is dependant on the maximum "Count" value of the dataframe and this approach does not work with different ranges of Count values.

Can someone tell me how I can make the position of the labels [in blue] independent of the dataframe used? Is there a way to use something like "pad = 10" for annotations?

[image: Current output]

I am using the code below:

```
import numpy as np ; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; import pandas as pd

Row1, Row2, Row3, Row4 = ['A',180,2], ['A',270,6], ['A',360,3], ['B',360,2]
df_polar = pd.DataFrame([Row1, Row2, Row3, Row4]);
df_polar.columns = ['Type', 'Angle', 'Count']

deg = np.pi/180
width = 30*deg
fig = plt.figure() 
fig.set_size_inches((12, 7), forward=False)

i=0; x = np.array(df_polar['Type']);  Total_types = np.unique(x)



for Type in Total_types:

   i+=1
   df_plot = df_polar[df_polar['Type'] == Type].set_index('Angle')
      
   Angle =  np.array(df_plot.index.tolist())
   theta = Angle = Angle * deg
 
   count = radii = df_plot['Count'] 
   ymax = max(count)

   label_pos_r = ymax + .7

   colors = plt.cm.viridis(df_plot['Count'] / 4.)

   ax = fig.add_subplot(1,len(Total_types),i, projection='polar')
   ax.bar(theta, count, width=width, bottom=0, color=colors, alpha=.6)
   ax.set_thetagrids(range(0, 360, 30))
   ax.set_theta_zero_location("N") 
   ax.tick_params(direction='out', pad = 20)
   ax.tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=8)
   ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
   ax.set_rlabel_position(15) 
   ax.set_title(Type, fontsize=15)

   ##### Add labels #####
   label_pos_theta = np.array(range(0,346,15)) ; label_val = [1]*len(label_pos_theta)
   dummy_labels = {'Angle': label_pos_theta, 'Labels': label_val}

    
   df2 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_labels)
   df2.columns = ['Angle','Labels']
   df2['Labels'] = df2['Labels'].astype(int) 

   ##########


   for pos, label in zip(df2.Angle, df2.Labels):
    ax.annotate(label, xy=(pos*deg, label_pos_r), xytext=(0, 0), textcoords="offset pixels", 
                color='blue', ha='center', va='center',  fontsize = 8, annotation_clip = False)

        
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `label_pos_r = ymax * 6.7/6` to always get the same pos as in the first chart where `ymax` was 6.

Comment: well, as long as your r axis ranges from `0` to `ymax` in each plot the label should be at the same relative position, shouldn't it? It doesn't depend on the dataframe used.

Comment: My bad, I misread your formula before. I have accepted your suggestion as a solution. Thank you @Stef. Also how did you come up with this value (6.7/6)?

Comment: simple rule of three based on the first plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Stef's comment, the solution is to use:

```
label_pos_r = ymax * 6.7/6
```